# How to disable device plugged in notification dialog box in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: sound, notification

There is something wrong with my laptop on the hardware level where it constantly keeps thinking that an audio device has been plugged in. It happens with little movements like resting my palm near the keyboard. Whenever it happens, the audio device plugged in dialog box pops up and it's really become irritating since it sometimes happens every 10 seconds. Since I can't solve the hardware problem without opening the laptop up, can I disable the dialog pop up so that at least I don't get disturbed and irritated every 10 seconds?

Attached a screenshot of the pop up.

[image]